# Ajax form submitting but not redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a Sign Up form using jQuery validation plug-in with PHP for server side scripting.The form is correctly submitting data to the database but after submission it shows a blank page with the URL for the page containing that form in the address bar.In other words after submiting data the form just disappear and the html page become blank.Here is a piece of javascript code responsible for form submission when after successful validation

```
function submitForm()
{
    var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'register.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
        },
        success :  function(data)
        {
            if(data==1){

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry email already taken !</div>');

                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });

            }
            else if(data=="registered")
            {

                $("#btn-submit").html('Signing Up');
  //The line below seem to be the culprit 
                setTimeout('$(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){      $(".signin-form").load("successreg.php"); }); ',5000);

            }
            else{

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
/* form submit */

});
```

The code is not redirecting to `successreg.php` any help?

Comment: A. ) You're not using a redirect. B.) Your `load()` function is either not reached or is failing. [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: The arguments for setTimeout are `setTimeout(function, delay);`.  You are trying to give it a string instead of a function for it to execute after the delay elapses.

Comment: else if(data=="registered")
            {

              alert('enter'); 

            }
check alert is working

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes you are right i guess, I was also suspecting  that my `load()` is failing me I will try diuheato's answer and Taplar's suggestion.I am running this on local server.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` first argument is callback. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(".signin-form").load("successreg.php");
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to this:

```
  //some code goes here
 else if(data=="registered")
            {
                window.location.href = "successreg.php";
            }
  //more code continue
```

and  it worked fine.I am not sure if it's the right way of doing it since I have seen some down votes to an answer suggesting what I did.